# Does the visual studio can add a .cs files to the project when user creates a class file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way for visual studio to create .cs files and add to the project after I manually create a class file?

As if it were an event of visual studio or something else.

When the user manually create a class file inside Entities folder, the visual studio capture the event and automatically create 2 interfaces and 2  classes that implements these interfaces.

Is there a way to perform this?

Comment: What is the "Entries" folder?

Comment: Entities folder, is a folder located in a library that I use

Comment: You may take a look at T4

Comment: Searching about T4 now, ty